# Getting objects within array not present in other array

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have 2 arrays. The first array contains the full list of my objects and the second array contains objects that I got from the first array.

My question is how can I get objects from the first array not present in the second array? So I have tried something like this, in which I create a temporary array. This is my code:

```
var violators = CSR.ViolatorDetails.violators.slice();
        $.each(collectedFrom, function(idx, obj){
            var obj = Main.Objects.get_object(CSR.ViolatorDetails.violators,obj.violator_id,'violator_id');
            //the object is in CRS.ViolatorDetails.violators    
            if(obj != null){
                var i = CSR.ViolatorDetails.violators.indexOf(obj);
                console.log(i);
                if(i >= 0){
                    console.log('Removing');
                    violators.slice(i,1);
                }
            }
        });
```

CSR.ViolatorDetails.violators contains the full list of my object.
collectedFrom contains objects that I get from the first array.
violators is the temporary array I have created.

Your responses would be greatly appreciated.

You can suggest if I can change my approach or just have to change something within my code.

Thanks.

Comment: So, `collectedFrom` is the smaller array, and `CSR.ViolatorDetails.violators` is the bigger array?

Comment: Do a search for "array difference" and you will find quite a few examples.

Comment: My answer (now deleted) was basically the same as http://stackoverflow.com/a/4026828/710446

Comment: yup thanks. Sorry, unfamiliar with the term array difference =) Thanks anyway.